# Meaning of "See the man"

Tags: production, adam-12

The classic show **Adam-12**, like Jack Webb's other show **Dragnet**, was exactingly precise in its portrayal of the police, and of police procedure.

Shaaron Claridge, who played the dispatcher, was an actual police dispatcher.

I recall hearing (possibly on one of Nick at Nite's little vignettes) that the phrase "see the man", used in many of the calls to the officers, had a different, or more specific meaning than simply "a man called this issue in", but I can't find any references to it now. It might have meant that there was already on officer on the scene, but I may be making that up in my zeal to recall the answer.

Does this ring any bells for anyone? Might this be better placed in a group that deals with actual police procedure, perhaps?

Comment: It just means that the man reporting the issue is at the specified location, nothing more.